# Writing the integral $\int\limits_{\pi}^{N \pi} \frac{|sin \theta|}{|\theta|} d\theta $ as sum.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Write the integral $$\int_{\pi}^{N \pi} \frac{|sin \theta|}{|\theta|} d\theta $$ as a sum  $$\sum_{k = 1}^{N-1} \int_{k \pi}^{(k+1)\pi}$$

Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: $[\pi,N\pi]=[\pi,2\pi]\cup\ldots\cup[(N-1)\pi,N\pi]$ and $\sin(\pi+\theta)=-\sin\theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the fact 
$$\int_a^b+\int_b^c=\int_a^c$$
we get
$$\int_{\pi}^{N \pi} \frac{|sin \theta|}{|\theta|} d\theta=\sum_{k = 1}^{N-1} \int_{k \pi}^{(k+1)\pi} \frac{|sin \theta|}{|\theta|} d\theta$$